# Check a condition based on argument in clojure/tinsel template macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to use the [tinsel HTML template library](https://github.com/davidsantiago/tinsel) to delete a node if the user is nil, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to evaluate the conditional, since everything is based on macros.

This version doesn't work because it evaluates `user` to a form `'user` during compile time, which is not nil, so hard-sets the true branch, and never re-evaluates.  (Feel free to correct my terminology if that was not quite correct).

```
(tc/deftemplate folder-list
  (tc/html-document (slurp "resources/templates/folders.html"))
  [user]
  (tc/id= :mnuUsers)
  (fn [node] (do (prn 'user) (if 'user node nil))))
```

Here's the closest I've got, which does in fact print the user at render time rather than compile time, and branches correctly, but throws an error saying Unable to resolve symbol `node`.

```
(tc/deftemplate folder-list
  (tc/html-document (slurp "resources/templates/folders.html"))
  [user]
  (tc/id= :mnuUsers)
  (fn [node] '(do (prn user) (if user node nil))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not ever used Tinsel, but I'll take a shot in the dark...does this work?

```
(t/deftemplate folder-list
    [[:h1#mnuUsers "header"]]
    [user]
    (t/id= :mnuUsers)
    (fn [node] 
       (list 'if 'user node nil)))
```

My normal approach would be to use syntax quotes and unquoting. However, I couldn't get that to work. The above builds an expression out of a list of symbols...it seems ugly but it might do the trick.

**EDIT**

Version that uses syntax quoting instead:

```
(t/deftemplate folder-list2
  [[:h1#mnuUsers "header"]]
  [user]
  (t/id= :mnuUsers)
  (fn [node]
    `(if ~'user ~node nil)))
```

Comment: Works! Is it possible make a macro `hide-if` so I can just use `(hide-if (nil? user))` as the last form?

Comment: Got it: ``(defmacro hide-if [b] (fn [node] `(if ~b nil ~node)))``.  Feel free to simplify or generify if possible.

Comment: Oddly that *worked* (in repl), but didn't *compile* (using `lein compile`), which doesn't seem to make sense (to me) *at all*, but nonetheless it is so.  The following compiles as well.  ``(defmacro hide-if [b] (let [b# b] `(fn [node#] (list 'if (quote ~b#) nil node#))))``.